# How can I create network plot in one column based on another column?

Tags: r, asp.net-mvc

I want to create network plot in one column based on another column.
Here an example of what my data frame looks like:

> 

```
## project-ID ## ## Area-ID ##
     1                2
     1                3
     1                5
     2                4
     2                2
     2                3
```

so the network plot will show the relation between AreaID, I didn't found any idea that will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the `data.frame` to an `igraph` object, and plot the graph.

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "project-ID Area-ID
     1                2
     1                3
     1                5
     2                4
     2                2
     2                3", header = T)

# Convert data.frame to igraph and plot 
library(igraph);
ig <- graph_from_data_frame(df);
plot(ig);
```

[image]

Many resources involving plotting and analysing networks/graphs using `igraph` can be found online, e.g. [here](https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2008/slides/Csardi.pdf), [here](http://igraph.org/redirect.html), [here](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/research/friday/resources_WS0708_SS08/igraph.pdf), ...